# Force expander to take all available space

Tags: wpf, layout

I got something like:

```
1) <grid> with some rows -> 2) <stackPanel> -> 3) Expander -> 4) Expander content...
```

..and I can't force expander content to be stretched as long and as wide as possible by currently free space in the given grid.row (#1). Whatever I try, expander keeps using to take minimum necessary space to renders its content. But if I do something like `MinHeight=500`, then it's OK.

P.S. I had an idea to hack it. Just to create transparent line, stretched through the row, and then bind expander height to the actual height.. but it seems ugly to me. Maybe someone knows another way?

```
<Grid Name="GlobalPanel" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.7*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="0.3*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Vertical">
        <Expander Name="MainExpander"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <!-- HERE EXPANDERS CONTENT WHICH I WANT TO BE STRETCHED -->
        </Expander>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Try using a Grid instead of a StackPanel.